# Correct way to protect flask-sentinel oauth management

Tags: python, flask

flask-sentinel creates a route to a management UI [using app.add_url_rule](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/flask-sentinel/blob/904a2dba5311252936c992e57e05b7b0c6f29410/flask_sentinel/flask_sentinel.py#L37). Wanting to apply some access control rules I wrapped it like this:

```
from flask.ext import sentinel

def requires_auth(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        roles = []
        if 'user' in session and 'roles' in session['user']:
            roles = session['user']['roles']

        if 'admin' not in roles:
            flash("Not enough power")
            return redirect('/')

        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

sentinel.views.management = requires_auth(sentinel.views.management)
sentinel.ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials(app)
```

The question is, is this really the way or is there some more appropriate way?

**EDIT:**
Realized that my question was rather abstract and really just about flask instead of sentinel. Guess what I meant to ask was: "is there any more declarative way to apply security restrictions to paths in Flask, instead of wrapping each registered route one by one?"
After a bit of study, this seems to provide the flexible security control I was looking for.

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask('bla')

PATH_ROLES = {
    '/admin/.*': ['admin']
}

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    try:
        rule = next(x for x in PATH_ROLES if re.match(x, request.path))
        print "path requires: ", PATH_ROLES[rule]
    except StopIteration: pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At quick glance I'd say that your approach is sound. You are essentially applying the common Flask pattern of [wrapping a view with a decorator](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/).

Comment: Yep, it just seemed hackish applying a decorator programmatically instead of as declaration to the view. Trying out some other approaches, thanks for the review though. :)